# Understanding Error: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript

I've seen a few questions with this error, and mine had a different solution. Perhaps someone could explain this? I understand that I need to convert the JSON response into a string, but the error message made no sense to me in that regard.

```
var root = "someurl";
url = root + url;
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: url,
   data: formData,
}).done(function (response) {
   // Fails with error: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
   document.getElementById("resultBox").appendChild(response);

   // OK
   document.getElementById("resultBox").textContent = JSON.stringify(response, null, 4);
}
```

Comment: It's just as the error says. You cannot call `appendChild` with something that isn't a node. Neither a string (nor an object) is a node. Is something wrong with your `textContent` solution?

Comment: No, the textContent version works fine. I suppose I was confused by the language "failed to execute appendChild on" taking that to mean the span returned by getElementById.

Comment: Functions take parameters - the error is saying that the first parameter you passed to `appendChild` (that is, the `response`) is not a Node. (If `resultBox` wasn't an element, it would have thrown earlier, when you tried to access the `appendChild` property)

Answer (score 1):

## [`.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

The [`.appendChild`] function needs the first parameter as a [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node).

Any one of the following interface is considered a `Node`:

1. [`Document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document)
2. [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)
3. [`Attr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Attr)
4. [`CharacterData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CharacterData)
5. [`ProcessingInstruction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProcessingInstruction)
6. [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)
7. [`DocumentType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentType)
8. [`Notation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notation)

Anything that is not one of the above is not considered a `Node`. Therefore, when you pass an object or a string (the `response`), the following error is raised:

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

The `response` returned by ajax request is most likely an [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

`JSON.stringify` will transform an `Object` into [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).

Both are not one of the listed interface.